# Loading the specific page on Browser Refresh. SPA AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

I am creating a new Web API and Angular application. I want to know how we can handle routes on server side. Everything is working fine. I am using `ui-router` for routing, when i refresh browser that its giving me.

> **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**

I want to know how we can handle this.

Code for ui-router

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: templatesDirectores.wmAccount + 'login.html',
    controller: 'login-controller',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
})
    .state('register', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: templatesDirectores.wmAccount + 'register.html',
    controller: 'register-controller',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
})
    .state('forgetPassword', {
    url: '/forgetpassword',
    templateUrl: templatesDirectores.wmAccount + 'forget-password.html',
    controller: 'forget-password-controller',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

The view is loading fine as per the configuration, but when the URL is `localhost:1235/register`, it's loading fine first time but when I hit the refresh button I get 404 error.

Comment: please submit more information and code.

Comment: Are you using `HTML5Mode` in your application by chance?

Comment: Instead of showing pseudo url.could you please update your question what exact url you tried..

Comment: based on your edit, it appears you **are** using `HTML5Mode`.  This requires additional setup on your server to ensure that it works properly.  see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: which server technology are you using?

Comment: WebApi and AngularJS

Comment: ok, so IIS is serving the base HTML page then....

Comment: yes...and i don't have a basic directory for views. its all depends on the angular module we are loading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is occurring because you are using `HTML5Mode = true` in your Angular Application.  Angular uses "hash" (`/#register`) routes to handle it's routing by default, in order to ensure that the browser does not perform a page reload from the server.

Using `HTML5Mode`, you can suppress the `#`, but at a cost.  The browser must be HTML5 compliant, because HTML5Mode uses HTML Push State ([HistoryAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/history.html)).

Also, your server must be configured to handle requests for routes which may exist in Angular but do not exist on the server.  When you directly load a page, either by typing it in or by using refresh, a request is sent to the server, with a URL that the server may not know how to handle.  Your server should be configured to return your `Index.html` page for any routes it does not expressly handle.  This configuration [varies per server](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode).

Given you stated you are using IIS to host your site, something like the following would be necessary:

Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                                 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Essentially, for all routes (`.*`), if the request is not a file or a directory, rewrite the url to return the base URL `/`.

This can also be done in code, something similar to this:

Global.asax:

```
private const string ROOT_DOCUMENT = "/default.aspx";

protected void Application_BeginRequest( Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
    if ( !System.IO.File.Exists( Context.Server.MapPath( url ) ) )
        Context.RewritePath( ROOT_DOCUMENT );
}
```

There are a few other caveats here:

1. Each platform handles rewrites differently.  In the case of IIS, the URL is rewritten, and the remainder of the route is lost.  i.e. for `localhost:1235/register`, you will actually load `localhost:1235/`, and Angular will never receive the `/register` route.  Essentially, all routes not known by IIS will return your app entry point.
2. You can set up multiple entry points to your app, but any in-memory references to variables, settings, etc. will be lost when moving from one entry point to another.

Given these two points, you should **always** consider any external URLs to be a fresh copy of your Angular application, and handle them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to reroute 404's to your SPA:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/spa-location.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
 </system.webServer>
```