# When I navigate to a route directly i get server output, but when I use a link i get the view rendered correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meanjs

I'm a noob and working on mean.js boilerplate.

I've created some routes, but I'm having an issue, where, when I navigate to a certain route ('/articles') i get server output like this:

> [{"_id":"5553aa4116a2fddc830b0f66","user":{"_id":"5552398fcf7ada7563db68b7","displayName":"Mo
>   Bazazi"},"__v":0,"content":"WAHATTATA","title":"Fifth
>   Examples","created":"2015-05-13T19:47:13.905Z"}]

but i want to ge the rendered view, even when I manually type in the route - does anyone have any suggestions?

here part of my express config

```
use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    https = require('https'),
    express = require('express'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    compress = require('compression'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    helmet = require('helmet'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')({
        session: session
    }),
    flash = require('connect-flash'),
    config = require('./config'),
    consolidate = require('consolidate'),
    path = require('path');

module.exports = function(db) {
    // Initialize express app
    var app = express();

    // Globbing model files
    config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/models/**/*.js').forEach(function(modelPath) {
        require(path.resolve(modelPath));
    });

    // Setting application local variables
    app.locals.title = config.app.title;
    app.locals.description = config.app.description;
    app.locals.keywords = config.app.keywords;
    app.locals.facebookAppId = config.facebook.clientID;
    app.locals.jsFiles = config.getJavaScriptAssets();
    app.locals.cssFiles = config.getCSSAssets();

    // Passing the request url to environment locals
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals.url = req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + req.url;
        next();
    });

    // Should be placed before express.static
    app.use(compress({
        filter: function(req, res) {
            return (/json|text|javascript|css/).test(res.getHeader('Content-Type'));
        },
        level: 9
    }));

    // Showing stack errors
    app.set('showStackError', true);

    // Set swig as the template engine
    app.engine('server.view.html', consolidate[config.templateEngine]);

    // Set views path and view engine
    app.set('view engine', 'server.view.html');
    app.set('views', './app/views');
```

So Claies was right - this is an HTML5 issue -  I've been working on this a little and trying to set up a catch all for express config - I've added this section below:

```
// Setting the app router and static folder
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.render('index');
    });

    // Globbing routing files
    config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/routes/**/*.js').forEach(function(routePath) {
        require(path.resolve(routePath))(app);
    });

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('/');
    });
```

The problem is that I'm using mean.js boilerplate, and they have custom glob based routing, which doesn't play well with my catchall i.e. my resources wont work properly with the catchall as they are, although they are rerouting to the correct templates - any thoughts?

Comment: you might want to try rewording your title for clarity

Comment: it sounds like you have the same route on the server and in the client, and are using `HTML5Mode` in your Angular application.  This configuration will not work the way you expect.  I've written a few articles on `HTML5Mode`, the latest one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194729/loading-the-specific-page-on-browser-refresh-spa-angularjs/30196347#30196347.  That article describes an IIS configuration, but the concepts are similar across all server technology.  In effect, you can't have routes on both the server and client with `HTML5Mode`.

Comment: Hi Claies - i've made an edit above, adn would appreciate your thoughts